# How to change appearance of AutoComplete suggestions in an UltraComboEditor?

Tags: winforms, autocomplete, combobox, infragistics

The UltraComboEditor of Infragistics has an AutoComplete feature that displays suggestions in a popup as the user types.

The part typed by the user appears **bold** :

[image]

To comply with our graphic chart, we need the suggestions to be colored instead of **bold**.

In general, I would like to control the way suggestions are displayed.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provided a possible solution using a draw filter that you could use here: http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/59583/338866.aspx#338866

Answer (score 0):

I was told by the IG support there is not way.
So I made a feature request, asking for a set of AutoComplete*something*Appearance properties.